# Using neo4jRb Gem, how do I get the relationship on a has_one association

Tags: neo4j, neo4jrb

So I created a has_one and has_many relationship with neo4j

```
class Client

    has_one  :out , :room,  model_class: :Room,rel_class: :AssignedTo

end

class Room
  has_many  :in , :clients, rel_class: :AssignedTo, model_class: :Client

end

class AssignedTo
    include Neo4j::ActiveRel
    from_class :Client
    to_class :Room
    type 'assigned_to'
    property :from_date, type: DateTime
    property :to_date , type: DateTime
end
```

I want to accept the Assigned_to relationship from room to client
room.clients.each_with_rel works fine
but I can't find a way to access the relationship the other way around: 
client.room.rel 
All the methods i tried client.room.rel,relationship, assigned_to etc don't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Since `client.room` is a `has_one` relationship, by default neo4jrb gets the association proxy, and then plucks the first (and only) result, returning the `room` object. The `room` ActiveNode object doesn't have an `.each_with_rel` method.

Using the latest version of the Neo4jrb gem (dunno which version you are using) you can do `client.room(chainable: true).each_with_rel do |node, rel|` which should work, same as `room.clients.each_with_rel do |node, rel|`.

The `chainable: true` option for `has_one` associations tells neo4jrb to return an association proxy (which is what you always get with a `has_many` association).